# /dev/sda1 is mounted; will not make a filesystem here!

Tags: linux, raspbian

I try to mount a 16GB USB Stick in Raspbian on my Raspberry Pi 3. I tried this command, but it dosent work:

```
sudo mkdir /share
```

Here's my attempt in full:

```
$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1
mke2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
/dev/sda1 contains a ext4 file system
last mounted on Thu Feb 16 15:48:05 2017
Proceed anyway? (y,n) y
/dev/sda1 is mounted; will not make a filesystem here!
$ sudo mkdir /share
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/share’: File exists
```

Edit:  I tried this tutorial in german: http://www.welzels.de/blog/projekte/raspberry-pi/low-budget-nas-mit-einem-raspberry-pi/pi-nas-einbinden-der-usb-festplatte/ the main point: i want to put a data file into the usb stick, but the permission denied

Comment: perhaps I'm misreading this : are you trying to mount a USB drive with mkfs.ext4?

Comment: I tried this tutorial in german: http://www.welzels.de/blog/projekte/raspberry-pi/low-budget-nas-mit-einem-raspberry-pi/pi-nas-einbinden-der-usb-festplatte/  the main point: i want to put a data file into the usb stick, but the permission denied

Comment: Please add the output of this command to your question (use the [edit] button, above) - `mount | grep sda`. It will show you where the USB stick can be found in the filesystem.

Answer (score 9):

For raspberry pi  (on raspberry pi 4b ) I used `sudo umount -fl /dev/sda1` . Then I was able to format using `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1`

Answer (score 4):

Couple of things (which the messages you are seeing are telling you, but I shall expound):

Firstly, the directory creation:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mkdir /share 
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/share’: File exists
```

You can't create what's already there.  `ls -ld /share` will show you what exists at `/share`; if it is not a directory but rather a file, it will need to be deleted, moved, or renamed before a new item with that name can be created at that location (indeed, the same would also apply if it were a directory, link, socket, or other filesystem entity).

Secondly, the filesystem creation:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1 
mke2fs 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014) /dev/sda1 contains a ext4 file system last mounted on Thu Feb 16 15:48:05 2017 
Proceed anyway? (y,n) y 
/dev/sda1 is mounted; will not make a filesystem here!
```

This is telling you exactly what the problem is- you can't `mkfs` on a partition that's currently mounted and thereby in use.  You can try `umount /dev/sda1`, but that might not work if that's actually the root filesystem.  Check this with `mount`.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I only want to put one file in my USB Stick with the Raspberry Pi. But if i try to put a file in my USB Stick it comes : permission denied. So what is the way to put a file to my usb stick

Comment: MajorTom, what makes you feel your USB stick is /dev/sda1?

Answer (score 1):

The `mkfs` command you try to execute is for formatting a partition with an ext4 filesystem. A USB drive should already come formatted (with vfat, the DOS/Windows filesystem); no need to do this if all you want to do is to copy a file onto it. And `mkdir /share` would create a subdir under the root directory, not on your USB drive.

The HowTo you linked is for a very special case, using a NAS on the Raspi. It doesn't sound as if you want to do this, and I guess you picked the wrong Google result for your issue.

What you really want to do can be achieved with the `mount` and `cp` commands; there should be enough HowTos outside, also targetted at the Raspi, that should be able to show you how.